# How to make EKS Blueprint create nodes with custom Security Groups?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I have 1 EKS cluster that I created using EKS Blueprint v4.21.0.

I want to expose some ports of my nodes, but I want these ports already exposed while creating the cluster via Terraform.
How can I make Terraform create the node-groups of the EKS cluster that is created via Blueprint, with custom Security Groups?
I tried in several ways, but I couldn't make an adjustment where the EC2 that are part of the managed node group use custom Security Groups with additional ip permission rules.

- Link to my project:
  https://github.com/fernandomullerjr/eks-via-terraform-github-actions/tree/main/09-eks-blueprint

I tried some parameter options in main.tf:

```
create_cluster_security_group
cluster_security_group_additional_rules

create_node_security_group
node_security_group_additional_rules

cluster_additional_security_group_ids
```

But they didn't work

I tried to do something like this, using the "additional_security_group_ids" for the "managed_node_groups", but it had no effect:

```
[...omitted...]
   managed_node_groups = {
     T3A_NODE2 = {
       node_group_name = "test2"
       instance_types = ["t3a.medium"]
       subnet_ids = module.vpc.public_subnets
       scaling_config = {
         additional_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.sg.id]
       }

     }
   }
```

What can be done in this case?

Comment: The question is kind of confusing. I took a look at the Github code and I don't see you are using any of the variables for custom SGs you mention. Can you add to the question what have you tried with the values and module call?